# how to proceed next?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We are required to find $x$ in $x^{86} \equiv 6 \pmod {29}.$

I tried solving it, and reached till $x^2 \equiv 6 \pmod {29}$ and got stuck. When I searched for the solution it directly mentioned that $x^2 \equiv 6 \pmod {29}$ is same as $x^2 \equiv 64 \pmod {29}.$

I have a doubt how come $x^2 \equiv 6 \pmod {29}$ same as $x^2 \equiv64 \pmod {29}.$

I am new to this website and concept, please forgive for any mistake

Comment: Euler's theorem states that for $a,n\in \mathbb{N}\text{ with } \gcd(a,n)=1$$$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1 \text{ (mod n) }$$and since 29 is prime, we can reduce the exponent of x mod 28, which gives $$6\equiv x^{86}=x^{2+3\cdot 28}\equiv x^2\text{ (mod 29) }$$and since in $\mathbb{Z_{29}}$, 6=64, we get our congruence.

Comment: @kalec The point is that $6 \equiv 64 \pmod{29}$. So, if $x^2 \equiv 6$, then $x^2 \equiv 64$ (by the transitivity of equivalence relations).

Comment: thanks @BenGrossmann & Fix

Comment: Well, $x^2\equiv 29k+6(mod 29)$  can you see that.

Comment: $$29 ~\text{divides} ~(x^2 - 6) ~\iff 29 ~\text{divides} ~(x^2 - 64).$$  This is because $$29 ~\text{divides} ~(64 - 6).$$